# JavaScript adding text from input and moving it beetwen divs

Tags: javascript

again newbee (my second) question:

I need to fill an empty list with

```
var todos = [
    {title:"Lorem ipsum 1",done:false},
    {title:"Lorem ipsum 2",done:true},
    {title:"Lorem ipsum 3",done:false},
    {title:"Lorem ipsum 4",done:true}
];
```

It needs to produce HTML like below:
(I have two divs: one groups (done:false), second groups (done:true))

<------- result -------->

**Div groups (done:false)**

Lorem ipsum 1
Lorem ipsum 3

**Div groups (done:true)**

Lorem ipsum 2
Lorem ipsum 4

<------- /result -------->

Now the fun beggins. After clicking on the element it needs to move it to the other div.
I need to have an submit form that will add input to the first div.

Anyhelp or advise in a good direction appriciated. I'm new to Js so not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = someContent;
```

Comment: Hi Cheers, but I said said I'm quite new into JS so that does not tel me much : )